# How to get the id of the window where the user is pressing a button?

Tags: swift, macos

In my macOS app I can have several open windows with text fields and buttons. As the user types some text and then presses a button, I need to retrieve the window's id in order to process the input in a window-specific mode.

I guess there is some simple solution, but I was not able to find it by looking into the documentation and at various posts. Please understand that I am new to Swift. If my questions are too naive for this site, please say so and I'll abstain.

Comment: Please post the code you have.

Comment: Thank you. I'll try and follow your suggestion. For a beginner, the existing Swift documentation is frustrating, as everything seems to refer to something else, endlessly.

Comment: Which object handles the button action?

Answer (score -1):

I found a provisional, basic solution to my problem. I guess it will be considered rudimentary, but I'll focus on refining my app's interface later. However, I'll be grateful for any suggested improvement. Essentially, I have a different `WindowGroup` for each elaboration mode, with a `var modeKey: Int` label that is also present in `ContentView` and is catched by my button. The windows can be opened in the File -> New menu. That's all. The drawback is that the number of modes is fixed. Thank you for your attention.

Here is the code for three modes:

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct example00App: App {
  var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup("modeKey: 0", id: "main") {
      ContentView(modeKey: 0)
    }
    WindowGroup("modeKey: 1", id: "1") {
      ContentView(modeKey: 1)
    }
    WindowGroup("modeKey: 2", id: "2") {
      ContentView(modeKey: 2)
    }
  }
}

struct ContentView: View {
  var modeKey : Int
  @State private var outputText = ""
  var body: some View {
    VStack(alignment: .leading) { Button(action: {outputText = "\(modeKey)"}) {
      Text("modeKey").padding(EdgeInsets(top: 10, leading: 1, bottom: 10, trailing: 1)) }
      TextEditor(text: $outputText)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I found an advanced answer to the problem, but it is not usable by a beginner: https://ondrej-kvasnovsky.medium.com/multi-window-swiftui-macos-app-working-with-menu-commands-4aff7d6c3bd6